# How to change the contents of a HTML tag every few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, css

I would like the subtitle (h2) to change every few seconds. What is the best way to achieve this?

I would prefer to keep it as simple as possible, preferably using bootstrap/jquery/ajax/css - but, if necessary, I could use a PHP solution.

You can see an example of this effect here: http://mattfarley.ca/

My html:

```
<div id="header" class="header">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6 wow bounceInLeft navbar-right">
                 <h1 class="navbar-right">Hello world</h1>
                 <h2 class="navbar-right">I wanna get off</h2>
                 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary navbar-right"">More Info</button>

             </div>

         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: "the best way".  By who's standards?  This is potentially a highly opinionated question.

Comment: What do you want to change the content too? Where is the new content coming from? What have you tried to date and what are the specific issues you are facing.

Comment: @JonP well that's part of my question. Where should I store the messages I want to display inside my <h2>.

Comment: We can't tell you where to store them as we don't know enough about them. How many? How random? How are they updated etc. There is no one "best way" that will suit all needs. Check the source of the page you have linked too for one simple way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use a `setInterval` to achieve what you want.

```
var message = 'I wanna get off';
var count = 0;
var msgInterval = setInterval(function(){
  $('h2').html(message.substr(0, ++count));
  if (count >= message.length){
    clearInterval(msgInterval);
  }
}, 400);
```

This should get you off to a good start.

Comment: Yes, it does helps to do the typing effect , but how do I set changing titles? For example I want the <h2 class="navbar-right">I wanna get off</h2> to change to "Hello Dolly". I actually want 4 different <h2> .

Comment: @SemSam you could always have an array of strings containing the different messages that you want to show. I was only giving you a starting point. You can always modify the code to pick each string in the array, and `display` it. You can also make it recursive if required.

Comment: I am sort of a newbie to all JavaScript, I'll use some more direction if it's not too much to ask...basically is that ,what you meant ?                       var message = ['I wanna get off',"Hello Dolly","Where is Waldo"];
var count = 0;
var msgInterval = setInterval(function(){
  $('h2').html(message.substr(0, ++count));
  if (count >= message.length){
    clearInterval(msgInterval);
  }
}, 400);